# Mysql Join Two tables on keys

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two tables, but seem to be having an issue, The output I am looking for is the amount of rows that there is subjects.

```
SELECT *
FROM education AS a
JOIN keys2 AS b USING(`List Idsubjek`)
WHERE `List Idsubjek` IN (52, 54, 55, 67)
AND `studentid` = '$id'
```

The keys2 table looks like this:

```
id List Idsubjek  Subject
1  52             Maths
2  53             Geography
```

The education table looks like this:

```
id List Idsubjek       studentid school
1  52,53,54,74,0,0,0   15        school name
```

What I currently have produces only one row, with an extra column "subject" but it only does the first one. Mathematics.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What value is passed in the variable `$id`? I'm surprised, I would expect an ambiguous column `List Idsubjekt` error if both tables have that column name. Please post a sample from the `education` table as well.

Comment: Have you tried INNER JOIN instead of JOIN? INNER JOIN syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: You need to define better the source tables (`education` specifically) and the desired result. Your `WHERE` statement includes `List Idsubjek IN (52, 54, 55, 67)` so as Geography is 53 it will be excluded. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @Paulo INNER JOIN is implicit when using just JOIN.

Comment: Hi Michael. Id is the student id. 900 or whatever. Only the education table have that in.

Comment: @anothershrubery I am trying to get a a result that looks like this:
Education's columns + one subject per row as a column name.

Comment: @anothershrubery I am trying to get a a result that looks like this:
Education's columns + one subject per row as a column name.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I see... Johan, may I see your table education?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should normalise your data structure an have a connection table between keys2 and education table.

To make the join work with the current data structure, use mysql's [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM education AS a
JOIN keys2 AS b on find_in_set(b.`List Idsubjek`,a.`List Idsubjek`)>0 
WHERE b.`List Idsubjek` IN (52, 54, 55, 67)
AND `studentid` = '$id'
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1052 - Column 'List Idsubjek' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Just add a table reference to the where clause.  WHERE b.`List Idsubjek` IN (52, 54, 55, 67)

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is surely redundant if using the `find_in_set` in the `JOIN`. It think this is where the confusion arises as he says he WANTS Geography to show, but it won't show with the `List Idsubjek IN (52, 54, 55, 67)` condition. Normalisation helps a lot as `find_in_set` isn't exactly efficient.

Comment: @JohanFourie placed a table reference in the where criteria, but you could have done this yourself as well.

Comment: @anothershrubery I completely agree, this is not the most efficient solution and I did point this out in the 1st sentence of my answer.