# Mysql - Combine two select queries, from two different databases in just one output

Tags: mysql

I am quite new to SQL stuff, and I am in situation where I don't have enough knowledge to achieve the following.

I am trying to combine the results of two select queries, but one query is from one data base and one for another . Both data bases are in the same server.

Like below :

On Database1 I run the query below :

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select GENRE,STYLE,CONTENT_ID,PROMO_END_DATE from Database1.PROMOTION_LIST ;
+-----------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| GENRE     | STYLE                                 | CONTENT_ID              |PROMO_END_DATE        |
+-----------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| ROCK      |Hard Rock,Opera Rock, Syphonic Rock    | 11111,22222,33333       | 2015-12-02 04:00:00  |
| METAL     |Black Metal, Death Metal, Heavy Metal  | 55555,66666,77777,22222 | 2015-12-29 11:00:00  |
| ELECTRO   |Dance, Tance, Flash House              | 88888,22222,66666,44444 | 2015-12-02 07:00:00  |
+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

On Database2 I run the query below :

```
SELECT SONG_ID,SONG_NAME,ARTIST FROM Database2.song_master_table

+---------+---------------+---------+
| SONG_ID | SONG_NAME     | ARTIST  |
+---------+---------------+---------+
| 11111   | SONG1         | BAND1   |
| 22222   | SONG2         | SINGER1 |
| 33333   | SONG3         | ARTIST1 |
| 44444   | SONG4         | BAND2   |
| 55555   | SONG5         | SINGER2 |
| 66666   | SONG6         | ARTIST2 |
| 77777   | SONG7         | BAND2   |
| 88888   | SONG8         | SINGER2 |
+---------+---------------+---------+
```

And the output I am trying to achieve is   :

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
| GENRE     | STYLE                                 | CONTENT_ID              |     ARTIST   | SONG_NAME     | PROMO_END_DATE     |
+-----------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
| ROCK      |Hard Rock,Opera Rock, Syphonic Rock    | 11111                   | BAND1        | SONG1         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
|           |                                       | 22222                   | SINGER1      | SONG2         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
|           |                                       | 33333                   | ARTIST1      | SONG3         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
| METAL     |Black Metal, Death Metal, Heavy Metal  | 55555                   | SINGER2      | SONG5         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
|           |                                       | 66666                   | ARTIST2      | SONG6         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
|           |                                       | 77777                   | BAND2        | SONG7         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
|           |                                       | 22222                   | SINGER1      | SONG2         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
|           |                                       | 33333                   | ARTIST1      | SONG3         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
| ELECTRO   |Dance, Tance, Flash House              | 88888                   | SINGER2      | SONG8         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
|           |                                       | 22222                   | SINGER1      | SONG2         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
|           |                                       | 66666                   | ARTIST2      | SONG6         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
|           |                                       | 44444                   | BAND2        | SONG4         | 2015-12-02 04:00:0 |
+-----------+---------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I tried to use join and union, but the syntax were not correct.

Consider that :

Database1,CONTENT_ID and Database2 SONG_ID are the same info. And I am not sure if possible, but the output will need to group the artist / song_name as per CONTENT_ID table. And there is no where condition.

I appreciate all and any help.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: First normalise your schema

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Join Two tables on keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896680/mysql-join-two-tables-on-keys)

Comment: This issue was solved here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/mysql-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases

Comment: @GoudaElalfy no, it was not.

Answer (score 0):

Add column `id` to `Database1.PROMOTION_LIST` then create another table which will connect this `id` with `SONG_ID`:

```
promo_id   song_id
1           11111
1           22222
1           33333
2           55555
...
```

Then it will be much easier to create the query you need.

Let me know if you need further help.