# Querying a comma separated column with a single id columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a result where a single column id is like a comma separated columns, my two table are as follows:

Room Location Table

[image]

Events Table

[image]

User Table

[image]

My query is

```
$sql=" SELECT users.*, events.*, room_location.* 
       FROM   events 
           INNER JOIN room_location ON events.event_room = room_location.location 
           INNER JOIN users ON room_location.user_loc_id = users.userlocationaccess 
       WHERE  room_location.user_loc_id LIKE '%1,2%'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

The query above works if I use single id in in the users->userGroupLocID.

How do I amend my query to work so it find if the id is like my comma separated columns?

Comment: _Smells like a bad mistake made in the original database design_ If its not too late, change the database design. This one will cause you nothing but problems. There is never a good reason for storing info in comma seperated lists in a table column

Comment: Yeah I wish I could rebuild the database, this is how the client setup the database, and I have to work with it as their are thousand of records stored.

Comment: @Craig: You can suggest the client to change it.

Comment: @Craig: btw, how would you want to search? by inputting a single user id or multiple ids?

Comment: @Craig : you are talking about `%1,2%` is present in `users` table not in `room_location`

Comment: Problem is what if you want to know if this column has a `1` in it and the column contains `3,5,11,21` Or `11` and it has `200,211`

Comment: @craig may be `FIND_IN_SET` will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Join Two tables on keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896680/mysql-join-two-tables-on-keys)

Answer (score 2):

You can search a CSV field using [**`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

**Example**:

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
    -> 2
```

**Documentation Says**:

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
>   string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters.

You can pass users location id to find in the column `userGroupLocID`

```
select find_in_set( location_id_in_search, replace( userGroupLocID, ' ', '' ) )
  from table_name;
```