# mySQL : How to code query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `clients` and `grades` where `clients` has a `grade` column with  indices from 1 to 10. Those indices correspond to the ID's in the `grades` table (of course). Let's say a client has the indices 1,5,8 in the `clients.grade` column than I want to fetch * from those rows in the `grades` table.

My first approach was to use a `grade` field of type char(20) in the `client` table and fill it with indices separated by commas like 1,5,8 or others numbers. Then reading those values from one client from the `client` table I explode (PHP) the result and getting an array with 3 (or more) single values. Then in a following query I select all those rows in the `grade` table .

Now one question is wether to use a char field or an enumeration field and the other (general) question is how to make a simple, clever query for the entire task.

I did not code it yet. The `grades` table will have max. 10 rows, where as the `client` table has around 2.000 rows growing up to max. 5.000 rows. I hope I could describe my approach understandable.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Join Two tables on keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896680/mysql-join-two-tables-on-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the `grade` column into a new table (`client_grade`?) containing `clientId` and `grade`, and have multiple records for each `client`. The grades for a client can then be retrieved using a `JOIN` from the `clients` to the `clients_grade` table on the `client` field

Each field in a table should hold a single piece of information and comma-separating values will cause you extra processing. Using a separate table will also aid you if you want to find out who got a particular grade etc

Comment: Thought about this already, but creating 10 colums in the client `table` itself. The problem is you have to validate each column in the `client` table and fetch the corresponding row in the `grade` table, which has to be done in an iteration. Or is there a better approach ?

Comment: The `client_grade` table would have two columns: `client_id` and `grade`. You insert multiple records in this table, one for each grade that a client achieves (i.e., if I achieve 3 grades, there would be 3 records). You then use a `JOIN` to retrieve the information from the three tables :  `client -> client_grade -> grades`. The other advantage of this system is that if a grade is disputed and subsequently changed, the update query would be a LOT simpler

Comment: Learn about table relationships and creating your schema in a sensible way. If a field needs to have more than one piece of data in it, it should become a table in its own right and have a relationship back to the master table

Comment: Sounds reasonable. +1 for this.  I will follow this answer and report later about the effort.